# How to send blocks within a same method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Having this method which can dynamically send args to an object:

```
module DSL
  def update object, *args, &block
    updated_object = object.send *args
    # then, some stuff with the updated object and the block
  end
end
```

the following code could be used such as:

```
include DSL

# equivalent to: Array.new 3, :foo
update Array, :new, 3, :foo do
  # updated object => [:foo, :foo, :foo]
  # some stuff
end
```

or such as:

```
# equivalent to: [:foo, :foo, :foo].size
update [:foo, :foo, :foo], :size do
  # updated object => 3
  # some stuff
end
```

But how could we update the content of this `update` method in order to handle blocks, like here:

```
[:foo, :bar].select {|a| a == :foo }
```

I thought about converting the block into a proc, such as:

```
update [:foo, :bar], :select, &:foo.method(:==) do
  # ...
end
```

But then, because a same method can not handle more than one block, this exception is raised:

> SyntaxError: both block arg and actual block given

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're going over the top with this, but anyway, here's an idea:

You could pass a regular proc to your `update` method and then have special handling for last argument, which is a proc.

```
module DSL
  def update object, *args, &block
    updated_object = if args.last.is_a? Proc
      proc = args.pop
      object.send *args, &proc
    else
      object.send *args
    end
    yield updated_object
  end
end

extend DSL

update [:foo, :bar], :select, ->(a) { a == :foo } do |obj|
  puts "selected object: #{obj}"
end

# >> selected object: [:foo]
```

Comment: Brillante! Thanks a lot, @sergio-tulentsev!